# Man who was a step away from Paradise, but went to Hell

Tags: hadith, source-identification, reference-request

I am trying to recall a hadith about a man who worshiped through out his life, but Iblees managed to deceive him in the last moment and he went to Hell; and another man of Hell went to Paradise likewise.

What was the complete version?

Answer (score 1):

[Here is one candidate:](https://sunnah.com/urn/1250760)

> 'Abdullah bin Mas'ud said:
>
> "The Messenger of Allah, the true and truly inspired one, told us
>   that: 'The creation of one of you is put together in his mother's womb
>   for forty days, then it becomes a clot for a similar length of time,
>   then it becomes a chewed lump of flesh for a similar length of time.
>   Then Allah sends the angel to him and commands him to write down four
>   things. He says: "Write down his deeds, his life span, his provision,
>   and whether he is doomed (destined for Hell) or blessed (destined for
>   Paradise)." By the One in Whose Hand is my soul! One of you may do the
>   deeds of the people of Paradise until there is no more than a
>   forearm's length between him and it, then the decree overtakes him and
>   he does the deeds of the people of Hell until there is no more than a
>   forearm's length between him and it, then the decree overtakes him and
>   he does the deeds of the people of Paradise until he enters therein."
>
> *> Sunan Ibn Majah, The Book of the Sunnah, English reference: Vol. 1,
>   Book 1, Hadith 76 Arabic reference: Book 1, Hadith 80*

Comment: It appears also in both sahihs: Sahih al-Bukhari [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/7), [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/80), [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/19) and [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/82/1) and in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/46/1), and [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/urn/722790) and [Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/42/113) so far the sources from sunnah.com

Comment: There are actually many similar ahadith, like [this](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/64/247) and [this](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/81/82). But I still miss Ibleess's impact in their content.